# Safari javascript console getElementById returning null

Tags: javascript, safari, console, getelementbyid

I am trying to find an element on a page and set its value from the safari console, I am able to get the exact same thing working on chrome but not safari. The page I am using is a Shopify payment page on this site https://kith.com. To reach it you have to add and item and pretend to checkout

Page should look like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIDPc.png]

The javascript I am using is

```
document.getElementById('number').value = '000011112222333';
```

Safari returns a TypeError: null is not a object message.

Here is the form code

```
<form>
    <label for="number" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">Credit Card Number</label>
      <input autocomplete="cc-number" id="number" name="number" type="tel" aria-describedby="error-for-number" data-current-field="number" class="input-placeholder-color--lvl-34" placeholder="Card number" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Lato; padding: 0.94em 0.8em; transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;">
      <span id="error-for-number" class="input-error-message visually-hidden"></span>

    <label for="name" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">Name on card</label>
      <input autocomplete="cc-name" id="name" name="name" type="text" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true" data-honeypot-field="" tabindex="-1">

    <label for="expiry_month" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">Expiry month</label>
      <input autocomplete="cc-exp-month" id="expiry_month" name="expiry_month" type="tel" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true" data-honeypot-field="" tabindex="-1">

    <label for="expiry_year" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">Expiry year</label>
      <input autocomplete="cc-exp-year" id="expiry_year" name="expiry_year" type="tel" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true" data-honeypot-field="" tabindex="-1">

    <label for="expiry" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">MM / YY</label>
      <input autocomplete="cc-exp" id="expiry" name="expiry" type="tel" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true" data-honeypot-field="" tabindex="-1"> 

    <label for="verification_value" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">CVV</label>
      <input autocomplete="off" id="verification_value" name="verification_value" type="tel" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true" data-honeypot-field="" tabindex="-1">

    <label for="issue_date" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">Issue date (MM / YY)</label>
      <input autocomplete="off" id="issue_date" name="issue_date" type="tel" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true" data-honeypot-field="" tabindex="-1">  

    <label for="issue_number" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true">Issue number</label>        
      <input autocomplete="off" id="issue_number" name="issue_number" type="tel" class="visually-hidden" aria-hidden="true" data-honeypot-field="" tabindex="-1">

    <button type="submit" class="visually-hidden" tabindex="-1">
<script src="https://checkout.shopifycs.com/build/boot-2a790b3233.js"></script>
```

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: Instead what is printing in console? Try `console.log(document.getElementById('number'));` and whether it returns an input Object or undefined.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Without that, you're asking us to read your mind.

Comment: @SagarV it returns undefined

Comment: The item is not available. Check inspect element and ensure the element is present in the page. and let me know these details?

Comment: @SagarV Yes when I inspect element it shows up. I can get the same exact  thing working in chrome so I am not sure if it has something to do with how safari console differs from chrome.

Comment: try console.log `document.getElementById;` and make sure it returns `function getElementById(){[native code]}`

Comment: @SagarV I just tried that in both safari and chrome. In chrome I got `function getElementById() { [native code] } ` and safari just undefined

Comment: in safari what did you get?

Comment: @SagarV undefined

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If `document.getElementById` itself is undefined, then trying to invoke it as a function the error message should say `document.getElementById is not a function`

Comment: @RyanBautista seems like JavaScript is disabled. check it to verify.

Comment: type `document` on console or `window` on console

Comment: @SagarV I think I just figured it out. In the safari console I found this [drop down menu](http://i.imgur.com/9cidG9I.png) that had main frame selected and other options for each element and when I switched it to the number option it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the order of the 'number' element and the script. The element must have been defined before the access via script.

Comment: he is accessing it from console